# Convert Milliseconds to HH:mm:ss format in Angular

Tags: html, angular, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to convert my milliseconds to readable Hour, minute, second format. I've tried to do this manually but I'm stuck, and I feel like there should be a simpler way.

Current manually written stopwatch:

```
ngOnInit(){
    //alert(this.datePipe.transform(new Date()));

    let timer = Observable.timer(0, 1000);
    timer.subscribe(t=>{
        this.today = this.datePipe.transform(t);
        this.second = t;
        if(this.second==60){
            this.second = 0;
            this.minute += 1;
        }else if(this.minute == 60){
            this.minute = 0;
            this.hour += 1;
        }

    });
}
```

Once the t passes 60 sec, seconds wont reset and it will continue to be over 60.

So my question is, is there a simpler way that actually works? I've read this and I don't quite understand how it works in my example [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

HTML

```
<div class="client-time">
    <span>Client time</span>
    <br/>
    <strong>{{hour}}:{{minute}}:{{second}}</strong>    
  </div>
</footer>
```

Basically I'm trying to show how long a user has been on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple version, showing the time in seconds:

*Component*:

```
private timer;
private counter: Date;

ngOnInit() {
  this.timer = Observable.timer(0,1000)
    .subscribe(t => {
      this.counter = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0);
      this.counter.setSeconds(t);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.timer.unsubscribe();
}
```

*Template*:

```
<div class="client-time">
  <span>Client time</span><br/>
  <strong>{{counter | date:'HH:mm:ss'}} seconds</strong>    
</div>
```

Comment: Showing the time in Seconds isn't the problem since this.timer = Observable.timer(0,1000); is already doing it. I want to show hour and minutes as well as seconds

Comment: @Fig, give me a sec, there's something wrong with the code - fixing it right now :)

Comment: @Fig, there working now, give it a try and let us know :)

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for, I knew I should habe been using the pipe function but didn't know how. This works perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: Only thing I'm having a problem with is that the seconds start at 14

Comment: @Fig really? I didn't see that on my own tests... Perhaps try addin this ".startWith(0)" right before the ".subscribe" call

Comment: @Brandon.Staley I spent at least 10 minutes of my own time coming up to that suggestion, testing and making sure is what he wanted. I saw your post after I was done with my own code, sorry that you feel like you were robbed. I think in the end we all just want to help, not steal things from each other. Gave you a vote up btw.

Comment: Ye ".startWith(0)" still makes it start at 14. Very strange. My exact code is :
`let timer = Observable.timer(0,1000).startWith(0);
  timer.subscribe(t=>{
   this.counter = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0);
   this.counter.setSeconds(t);
  });`

Answer (score 6):

To use DatePipe in combination with time take a look at the following:

```
  start = new Date(0,0,0);

  ngOnInit() {
    Observable.interval(1000)
      .startWith(0)
      .subscribe(t => {
        this.start = new Date(0, 0, 0);
        this.start.setSeconds(t);
      });
  }
```

And the HTML should be

```
{{start | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}
```